# Parse logs with SQL query to collect data in Log Parser Studio

Tags: sql

Excuse me for the question, my SQL knowledge is extremely limited. I'm trying to find anonymous connections in the exchange logs (I'm using Log Parser Studio which analyzes logs in bulk and parses them with SQL query). In the logs I see this:

```
#Fields: date-time,connector-id,session-id,sequence-number,local-endpoint,remote-endpoint,event,data,context
2020-01-10T01:01:01.111X,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,01C1Z111DD1X11Z1,212,192.168.1.1:21111,192.168.1.2:5565,*,,Proxying inbound session with session id 01C1Z111DD1X11Z1
2020-01-10T01:01:01.111X,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,01C1Z111DD1X11Z1,213,192.168.1.1:21111,192.168.1.2:5565,>,RSET,
2020-01-10T01:01:01.112X,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,01C1Z111DD1X11Z1,214,192.168.1.1:21111,192.168.1.2:5565,<,250 2.0.0 Resetting,
2020-01-10T01:01:01.112X,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,01C1Z111DD1X11Z1,215,192.168.1.1:21111,192.168.1.2:5565,>,XPROXYFROM SID=08D7F721DC0D9A14 IP=215,192.168.1.1 PORT=21111 DOMAIN=CONTOSO.COM SEQNUM=1 PERMS=1077 AUTHsrc=Anonymous,
2020-01-10T01:01:01.113X,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,01C1Z111DD1X11Z1,216,192.168.1.1:21111,192.168.1.2:5565,<,250 XProxyFrom accepted,
2020-01-10T01:01:01.113X,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,01C1Z111DD1X11Z1,217,192.168.1.1:21111,192.168.1.2:5565,*,,sending message with RecordId 151516 and InternetMessageId <j6hd87fh-55h6-66h6-5g55-k9dj47gk704z@VM1203102312.contoso.com>
2020-01-10T01:01:01.113X,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,01C1Z111DD1X11Z1,218,192.168.1.1:21111,192.168.1.2:5565,>,MAIL FROM:<test@contoso.com> SIZE=0 AUTH=<> XMESSAGEVALUE=MediumHigh,
2020-01-10T01:01:01.113X,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,01C1Z111DD1X11Z1,219,192.168.1.1:21111,192.168.1.2:5565,>,RCPT TO:<receive@contoso.com>,
2020-01-10T01:01:01.115X,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,01C1Z111DD1X11Z1,210,192.168.1.1:21111,192.168.1.2:5565,<,250 2.1.0 Sender OK,
2020-01-10T01:01:01.115X,Inbound Proxy Internal Send Connector,01C1Z111DD1X11Z1,211,192.168.1.1:21111,192.168.1.2:5565,<,250 2.1.5 Recipient OK,
```

So, I need to find data with "AUTHsrc=Anonymous" and then only show "IP", "MAIL FROM" and "RCPT TO" records from the session-id where "AUTHsrc=Anonymous" exists.

I managed to create a query to list only those IDs I'm after:

```
SELECT * FROM '[LOGFILEPATH]'
WHERE data LIKE '%AUTHsrc=Anonymous%'
```

But I don't know how to display other records based on my finding. I would assume I need a subquery?

[picture for the reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qcXB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't understand your wording, but the query below finds all unique `session-id`s with `AUTHsrc=Anonymous`

```
SELECT DISTINCT session_id FROM '[LOGFILEPATH]'
WHERE data LIKE '%AUTHsrc=Anonymous%'
```

And so this query will select all records with any of these `session-id`s

```
SELECT * FROM '[LOGFILEPATH]'
WHERE session_id IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT session_id FROM '[LOGFILEPATH]'
   WHERE data LIKE '%AUTHsrc=Anonymous%'
)
```

Put some particular columns instead of `*` to reduce the output to IP and all other data you're interested in.

Comment: I need to display "MAIL FROM:<test@contoso.com>", "RCPT TO:<receive@contoso.com>" and "IP=215,192.168.1.1" from a log, only if "AUTHsrc=Anonymous" exists.

Comment: do you want to put mail from rcpt to and ip in filter along wtih authsrc?

Comment: I guess so. If AUTHsrc is in text (within single session-id), then I want to have "mail from", "rcpt to" and "ip" displayed from that session-id.

Comment: @ArcaArcha it's not hard if your system has regular expressions support. I googled, and it appears it doesn't. So the easiest but not ideal way would be to add on the bottom `WHERE data LIKE '%IP=%' OR data LIKE 'MAIL FROM:%' OR data LIKE 'RCPT TO:%'`, but it will show 3 full rows, not just `IP=... MAIL FROM: ... RCPT TO:...`

Comment: very cool, thanks @AlexLarionov . I will process data with excel after.